# Simple bash script for opening a repository in the browser from the command line

Tags: bash

I'm relatively new to bash scripting, and I'm wondering how I've done on this. Basically it's a script where if I'm in a github or bitbucket repository in my terminal, I can type `browse-repository` to open it up in the browser. I can also type something like `browse-repository issues` to visit the issues page, or `browse-repository issues 19` to see issue # 19 for the repository.

I alias the command as `br` to save on typing, and can type things like `br i 19` to get to the page for issue # 19.

I'm mainly looking for tips on organization and scope, and of course if there's any other improvements as well. I couldn't figure out any sort of namespacing, so i prefixed commands with `_browse_repository`

The file as it currently stands is simple sourced from my `.bash_profile`, if that matters.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

function browse-repository() {
  local URL="https://$(git config remote.origin.url | sed 's/\.git//' | sed 's/https:\/\///' | sed 's/ssh:\/\///' | sed 's/git:\/\///' | sed 's/git@//' | tr ':' '/')"

  if _browse_repository_is_bitbucket_repo "$URL" || _browse_repository_is_github_repo "$URL"
  then
    case "$1" in
      "")
        URL="$URL"
        _browse_repository_go
        ;;
      i|issues|-i|--issues)
        if [[ -n $2 ]]
        then
          if _browse_repository_is_bitbucket_repo "$URL"
          then
            URL="$URL/issue/$2"
          else
            URL="$URL/issues/$2"
          fi
        else
          URL="$URL/issues"
        fi
        _browse_repository_go
        ;;
      p|pulls|-p|--pulls)
        if _is_bitbucket_repo "$URL"
        then
          URL="$URL/pull-requests"
        else
          URL="$URL/pulls"
        fi
        _browse_repository_go
        ;;
      w|wiki|-w|--wiki)
        URL="$URL/wiki"
        _browse_repository_go
        ;;
      h|help|-h|--help)
        _browse_repository_usage
        ;;
      *)
        _browse_repository_usage
        ;;
    esac
  else
    case "$1" in
      h|help|-h|--help)
        _browse_repository_usage
        ;;
      *)
        echo "Not a valid bitbucket or github repository"
        ;;
    esac
  fi
}

_browse_repository_is_bitbucket_repo() {
  [ "$URL" != "${URL#https:\/\/bitbucket.org\/}" ]
}

_browse_repository_is_github_repo() {
  [ "$URL" != "${URL#https:\/\/github.com\/}" ]
}

_browse_repository_usage() {
  cat <<EOF
usage: browse-repository [<command>] [<number>]

The following commands are performed on the current project.

Available commands:

  -i --issues [<number>] Open issues, optionally pass a number to open a specific issue
  -p --pulls             Open pull requests, optionally pass a number to open a specific pull request
  -w --wiki              Open wiki

When no argument is supplied the main project page will be opened.
EOF
}

_browse_repository_go() {
  open "$URL"
}
```

Comment: I saved your script and made it executable, and from a github Repository, i executed it but nothing happens..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things:

- You don't need the `function` keyword to define a function.
- You can combine `sed` commands by separating them by `;`: `sed 's/\.git//;s/https:\/\///;s/ssh:\/\///;s/git:\/\///;s/git@//'`
- This can be shortened down to a single statement: `sed 's/\(\.git\|https:\/\/\|ssh:\/\/\|git:\/\/\|git@\)//'`
- Fortunately you can get rid of picket fences in `sed` by using a different separator: `sed 's#\(\.git\|https://\|ssh://\|git://\|git@\)##'`
- I'd use `getopt` or `getopts` for option handling. Which one to use is a bit of a religious issue, but `getopt` supports long options (`--help` and the like), while `getopts` is more portable.
- It is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/96588) to use upper case only for variables exported in the shell, and lower case for other variables.
- This is maybe more of a personal preference, but rather than creating a *function* called I'd create a *script* with the same name and move the contents of the `browse-repository` function to the end of the script. That way there's no pollution of the function name space, and no need to source the script. Just put it for example at `/usr/local/bin/browse-repository` and run. An added advantage of this is that you don't need the function name prefixes anymore.
- I'm not sure how portable `open` is. On my system:

  ```
  $ open http://www.example.org
  Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
  ```

  Alternatively you could use `x-www-browser`, but I fear that's even less portable (Debian & derivatives only IIRC). I don't know if there's something more portable available.

All in all a very nice script.